# building APIs using API LM tools

Tags: api, apigee, tibco, mashery, 3scale

am new to API LM & confused about Building APIs using tools such as apigee, 3scale, mashery, mulesoft, TIBCO APIX etc

all these years , I know API is all about a language's API or SDK which you use to write/build code/application to solve a business problem. Say Java API or J2EE API etc

Do I have to build my own dataservice using my application/system and expose it as a service (WS/REST) and use the above tools (apigee, 3scale, mashery, mulesoft ec) or does these tools allow a developer to Build APIs from the scratch?

In other words, do I create your own application within your enterprise (be it Java based, DB or a .Net service or a Web App hosted on weblogic) and expose it as API for B2D or DX (with auth, analytics, portal, developer access) which is called as "build an API"?

Answer (score 0):

When using Apigee Edge, you must expose your backend as an http/https endpoint first.  Then, you can add security, caching, quota, and many other features to your API facade.  When using the Apigee-127 product, you can create an entire backend using Node.js locally and then deploy it to run in the cloud.